# Google maps Places API V3 autocomplete - restrict only allow to select hotels in canberra

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My new project need get address info from google map, but our service only pickup or dropoff from all the hotels in canberra.
My questions is how I restrict the autocomplete only choose the hotels in canberra.

Here is my code:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-35.3345571, 149.0334956, 15),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-35.1910655, 149.1817188, 12));

    var options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ['establishment'],
        keyword:'hotel',
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'au'
        }
    };

var input = document.getElementById('dropoff_address2Fromgoogle');    

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options); 

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('dropoff_address2Fromgoogle').value = place.name 
     + ", " + place.formatted_address
      + ", " + place.address_components[5].short_name;

});
```

I use bounds to bounds the area in canberra, but still search result will return other area, and Type filter only have establishment seem not return more result then I am expecting.

Comment: There is no option to restrict the results to a city. Using the bounds will only prefer these results, but didn't restrict the resuts to the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) that searches for hotels in a selected city.

Basically, the sample code makes calls to Google Maps APIs in two phases: one to search for a city (`onPlaceChanged()` was called), and another to search for hotels. In the latter search, you will call `nearbySearch()` on a Places object that has a `bounds` parameter from the city search and a `types` parameter with a value of `'lodging'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds) expects south-west and north-east corners.

Instead of:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-35.3345571, 149.0334956, 15),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-35.1910655, 149.1817188, 12));
```

It should be:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-35.1910655, 149.0334956),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-35.3345571, 149.1817188));
```